# Best way to search the path in shell

Tags: parsing, shell

I've got a small script called "onewhich".  Its purpose is to behave like `which`, except that it will only give the FIRST occurrence of any executables specified as options, as found in the order they'd appear in the path.

So for example, if my path is `/opt/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, and I have both `/opt/bin/runme` and `/usr/bin/runme`, then the command `onewhich runme` would return `/opt/bin/runme`.

But if I also have a `/usr/bin/doit`, then the command `onewhich doit runme` would return `/usr/bin/doit` instead.

The idea is to walk through the path, check for each executable specified, and if it exists, show it and exit.

Here's the script so far.

```
#!/bin/sh

for what in "$@"; do
  for loc in `echo "${PATH}" | awk -vRS=: 1`; do
    if [ -f "${loc}/${what}" ]; then
      echo "${loc}/${what}"
      exit 0
    fi
  done
done

exit 1
```

The problem is, I want to be better about PATH directories with special characters.  Every second shell question here on StackOverflow talks about how bad it is to parse paths with tools like awk and sed.  There's even a [bash faq entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) about it.  (Proviso: I'm not using bash for this, but the recommendation is still valid.)

So I tried rewriting the script to separate paths in a pipe, like this"

```
#!/bin/sh

for what in "$@"; do
  echo "${PATH}" | awk -vRS=: 1 | while read loc ; do
    if [ -f "${loc}/${what}" ]; then
      echo "${loc}/${what}"
      exit 0
    fi
  done
done

exit 1
```

I'm not sure if this gives me any real advantage (since `$loc` is still inside quotes), but it also *doesn't work* because for some reason, the `exit 0` seems to be ignored.  Or ... it exits *something* (the sub-shell with the while loop that terminates the pipe, maybe), but the script exits with a value of `1` every time.

What's a better way to step through directories in `${PATH}` without the risk that special characters will confuse things?

Alternately, am I reinventing the wheel?  Is there maybe a way to do this that's built in to existing shell tools?

This needs to run in both Linux and FreeBSD, which is why I'm writing it in Bourne instead of bash.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm what you really want to do?  It seems to me that if you walk through the path first, then `onewhich doit runme`  should return `/opt/bin/runme` before `/usr/bin/doit`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `sed` or `awk` to parse a PATH.  There is, however, something very wrong with using special characters in the path of any directory in your PATH!

Comment: oddly answered on the unix & linux stackexchange - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64160/whats-a-safe-and-portable-way-to-split-a-string-in-shell-programming

Comment: @ghoti You're right, that was unclear. I want it the way the code does it.  Walk through each command line option, then check every dir on the path, but only show the first one.

Comment: @Petesh Thanks, that link has some very useful tips.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but does eliminate the need to parse `PATH` at all:

```
onewhich () {
    for what in "$@"; do
        which "$what" 2>/dev/null && break
    done
}
```

This just calls `which` on each command on the input list until it finds a match.

---

To parse `PATH`, you can simply set `IFS=':'.

```
if [ "${IFS:-x}" = "${IFS-x}" ]; then
    # Only preserve the value of IFS if it is currently set
    OLDIFS=$IFS
fi
IFS=":"
for f in $PATH; do  # Do not quote $PATH, to allow word splitting
    echo $f
done
if [ "${OLDIFS:-x}" = "${OLDIFS-x}" ]; then
    IFS=$OLDIFS
fi
```

The above will fail if any of the directories in `PATH` actually contain colons.

Comment: I think OP is asking in more general terms, not for the specific case of `which`

Comment: One subquestion was "Am I reinventing the wheel?", to which the answer is "Yes". I'll update with one technique for parsing `PATH`, but it should rarely, if ever, be necessary.

Comment: As far as I know, `[[` is a bash ism.  I think I mentioned in the question that I'm not using bash.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. I'll fix to make it conform to POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method looks to me as if it should work.  In practical terms, if it's really the `$PATH` you'll be searching, it's unlikely you'll have spaces and newlines embedded in directories there.  If you do, it's probably time to refactor.

But still, I don't think you're at *risk* from the possibility of bad names clobbering your loop, since you're wrapping variables in quotes.  At worst, I suspect you might miss the odd valid executable, but I can't see how the script would generate errors. (I don't see *how* the script would miss valid executables, and I haven't tested - I'm just saying I don't see problems at first glance.)

As for your second question, about the loop, I think you've hit the nail on the head.  When you run a pipe like `this | that | while condition; do things; done`, the while loop runs in its own shell at the end of the pipe.  Exiting that shell may terminate the actions of the pipe, but that only brings you back to the parent shell, which has its own thread of execution that terminates with `exit 1`.

As for a better way to do this, I would consider `which`.

```
#!/bin/sh

for what in "$@"; do
  which "$what"
done | head -1
```

And if you really want the exit values as well:

```
#!/bin/sh

for what in "$@"; do
  which "$what" && exit 0
done

exit 1
```

The second might even be fewer resources, as it doesn't have to open a file handle and pipe through `head`.

You can also split your path using `IFS`.  For example, if you wanted to wrap your loops the other way around, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=":"

for loc in $PATH; do
  for what in "$@"; do
    if [ -x "$loc"/"$what" ]; then
      echo "$loc"/"$what"
      exit 0
    fi
  done
done

exit 1
```

Note that under normal circumstances, you might want to save the old value of `$IFS`, but you seem to be doing things in a stand-alone script, so the "new" value gets thrown out when the script exits.

All the above code is untested.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around the need to parse `PATH` at all is to run the builtin `type` command in new shell with a stripped environment (i. e. there simply are no functions or aliases to look up; cf. `env -i sh -c 'type cmd 2>/dev/null`).

```
# using `cmd` instead of $(cmd) for portability
onewhich() {
  ec=0  # exit code
  for cmd in "$@"; do
    command -p env -i PATH="$PATH" sh -c '
      export LC_ALL=C LANG=C
      cmd="$1"
      path="`type "$cmd" 2>/dev/null`"
      if [ X"$path" = "X" ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "error: command \"${cmd}\" not found in PATH" 1>&2
        exit 1
      else
        case "$path" in
          *\ /*)
            path="/${path#*/}"
            printf "%s\n" "$path";;
          *)
            printf "%s\n" "error: no disk file: $path" 1>&2
            exit 1;;
        esac
        exit 0
      fi
    ' _ "$cmd"
    [ $? != 0 ] && ec=1
  done
  [ $ec != 0 ] && return 1
}

onewhich awk ls sed
onewhich builtin 
onewhich if
```

Since `which` on success returns two full command paths if two commands are specified as arguments, `exit 0` in the first `onewhich` script above aborts the program prematurely. In addition, if two commands are specified as arguments to `which`, the exit code of `which` is set to `1` even if only one command lookup failed (cf. `which awk sedxyz ls; echo $?`). To mimic this behaviour of the `which` command it is necessary to toggle on/off two variables (`cnt` and `nomatches` below).

```
onewhich() (
   IFS=":"
   nomatches=0
   for cmd in "$@"; do
      cnt=0
      for loc in $PATH  ; do
         if [ $cnt = 0 ] && [ -x "$loc"/"$cmd" ]; then
            echo "$loc"/"$cmd"
            cnt=1
         fi
      done
      [ $cnt = 0 ] && nomatches=1
   done
   [ $nomatches = 1 ] && exit 1 || exit 0  # exit 1: at least one cmd was not in PATH
)


onewhich awk ls sed
onewhich awk lsxyz sed
onewhich builtin 
onewhich if
```